# SQL Server: Design Approach for Inserting Data

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have Employee Table having details like Employee_id, Address, Contact Number, and Employment Details.

I am trying to load above data in some different tables but the limitation is each field can be loaded via fixed length files.

For Example:

For loading Only Address Field,

```
**Field Position**
EID 1-4
Company 5-8
Address1 9-40
Address2 41-99
Status 100
```

For Loading Phone Number

```
EID 1-4
Company 5-8
phone 19-30
Landline 31-44
other 45-70
Status 100
```

For each field , We have around 40 Fixed length File Structure..

Could you please suggest an approch which i follow to make it more generic.

Thanks

Comment: unlikely you'll be able to create a generic solution, just write the insert statements and specify which source column is going to which destination column.

Comment: Thanks @tanner..If i do directly via Insert statement i have to make 40 structure..also I have to do validations before inserting for example Address 1 should not contain special symbol ..

Comment: You could add CHECK constraints to the destination table then handle exceptions for violations.

Comment: Are you importing this data from a file?

Comment: You could write a "generic" version for this but it would require dynamic sql and some persistent data to track the field layout. To be honest with only 40 or so formats I would just write 40 distinct insert statements. It would take a lot less time than a dynamic solution.

Comment: @CriticalError:Yes, I have to make fixed length flat files for inserting Data

Comment: @SeanLange: Thanks..Can I write a cursor nd  call procedures(40 Different procedure for each format)..nd Insert each output from different format in a table. Please suggest  if i am wrong

Comment: If you are calling 40 different procedures why do you think you need a cursor? Just call 40 procedures.

Comment: @SeanLange: I want to do this Exercise for all employees available in Employee Table  so that for Each Employee 40 files created and inserted in to table

Comment: If you have the data in a table already why are doing inserts via fixed width files? Why can't you simply use an insert statement?

Comment: @SeanLange: I am inserting Data from 1 Platform to another. We cant insert directly in 2nd platform. We need to do this by fixed length files..

Comment: I can only assume this must be some ancient system. No current system would have such restrictions. Is it a sql server database on both sides? You can do this quite easily, even across database types using the data export tool.

Answer (score 0):

If you are importing flat files into SQL Server you can use SS's BCP process to BULK INSERT your data. You can also provide BCP with a Format File where you can define your fixed length specification ( only have to do this once ) and then have it applied to bulk inserts moving forward.

Here is a link to Microsoft's Doc on importing bulk data and using a format file:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/import-export/use-a-format-file-to-bulk-import-data-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017

```
BULK INSERT dbo.myFirstImport   
   FROM 'D:\BCP\myFirstImport.bcp'   
   WITH (FORMATFILE = 'D:\BCP\myFirstImport.xml');  
GO
```

I believe this may be what you are looking for.